# How to disable access to a particular account via torbirdy

Tags: torbirdy

I have 3 mail accounts on thunderbird that connect to respective pop servers through torbirdy. I need to access one of these mail accounts without Tor for legal reasons. I have looked in my account settings and torbirdy preferences to make this possible (disable torbirdy for a particular account), but haven't found a solution. Is there some way to configure torbirdy/thunderbird to channel only 2 accounts via Tor and the third using conventional internet. Please help, I am a noob at this.

Answer (score 2):

Because of technical reasons (restricted by Thunderbird), it is not possible to apply the TorBirdy settings to specific email accounts.

Have a look at the [Transparent Torification](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/torbirdy/preferences#a-TransparentTorification) option, which allows you to keep all TorBirdy privacy settings intact *except* telling TorBirdy to use Tor (the proxy settings are cleared). This allows you to access a particular account without Tor since the proxy settings are cleared.

Be sure to read the warnings for this though (in the above link) since the network transmission will happen in the clear and **not** over Tor. Use this with caution! (There is a reason this option is labelled in red colour.)